# Factors affecting goroutine's performance

Tags: go

I'm experiencing some weird behaviors using goroutine and please provide advise or comments on things I might do wrong. Here is my process:

I am using goroutines to perform a simulation concurrently, but for some reason the time I spent increases with number of goroutines I put in which makes my simulation not possible to finish in a reasonable time. Here are the things I notice:

1. For every 10k goroutines initiated, the calculation time increases by 5 seconds
2. I don't see a shortage in CPU or memory. However CPU usage increases only a little bit for every 10k goroutines. For example when I put 200k goroutines, CPU usage is around 70%
3. I'm not using disks
4. I ran the simulation without triggering the goroutines and it finishes very fast, so the slowness is inside or due to goroutines
5. I tried to use additional goroutines in 1 occasion inside each goroutine to run some workload in parallel. CPU usage is boosted to 100% but the overall speed decreased by 50%...
6. I am passing some large structs to goroutines using pointers. All goroutines use the same data.

Does anyone have a clue on things I might need to optimize, or suggest me any test I can perform? Thanks!

Comment: Are your go routines modifying the struct's data?

Comment: If all your goroutines are running continuously (i.e., not blocking on I/O), you're not going to get any performance advantage by having more goroutines than the number of threads your system can run simultaneously. In fact, having more goroutines will slow things down because of the overhead involved in switching between them.

Answer (score 0):

Start few "worker" goroutines and send "jobs" to its via channel. You save many memory allocations that consume a lot of CPU.